Error while installing anchor
I'm getting below errors while installing anchor using commands :
-cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --force
-avm install latest
Errors Showing:
warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Operation too slow. Less than 10 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds) warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): [55] Failed sending data to the peer (Send failure: Connection reset by peer) warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [55] Failed sending data to the peer (Send failure: Broken pipe)
Please note that I'm installing it Solana all requirements locally. Rust installation succeeded, but got stuck here in anchor..
Thank you so much for your help!

are you behind a proxy? Not the most suitable method, but what about cloning the anchor repo and building the CLI locally.

Im not behind a proxy.
locally and not on the WSL you mean or how?
Also, this error is coming when installing the solana-verify cli using cargo install solana-verify --git https://github.com/Ellipsis-Labs/solana-verifiable-build --rev 13a1db2 --verbose 
Any other details to check ?
Thank you
